# Mouse not working when pressing Open With on a file in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, magic-trackpad

I have a very weird situation. In the finder application, if I right click a file and select Open With and Other, a new finder window pops up. In this new window, my mouse does not work - I cannot click or browser this finder window using my mouse. The mouse click only works makes this new window active, that is all.

[image]

[image]

In the first screenshot, I can use the mouse just fine. However, in the second screenshot, the mouse won't work at all.

This is driving me crazy. I thought maybe some settings in my bettertouchtool app might be causing this. But the only setting that I have for finder is  3 finger click to launch preview.

Comment: If you fully disable BBT, does it work? If you create a new user account on your Mac and try there, does it work?

Comment: god damn, I was able to make it work after just restarting mac.